# FFMPEG : av_open_input_stream in latest ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming

I was trying to read data from a buffer(instead of reading from file) for the purpose of live streaming.In the old version of FFMPEG it was supported using the API "av_open_input_stream". But in the FFMPEG version 2.2.2 this API apppears to be missing. I found the API "avformat_open_input" for reading from a file. Which API shall i use for the purpose of live streaming? It would be  very thankfull if you could show the steps for live streaming using the API.

Comment: What is your live-input source? is it a a camera? and on which operating system are you currently?

Answer (score 1):

You use avformat_open_input() for all inputs. From APIChanges:

`2011-06-16 - 2905e3f / 05e84c9, 2905e3f / 25de595 - lavf 53.4.0 / 53.2.0 - avformat.h
  Add avformat_open_input and avformat_write_header().
  Deprecate av_open_input_stream, av_open_input_file,
  AVFormatParameters and av_write_header`

If you'd like to not block on reading, you're recommended to put the code that calls avformat_read_frame() in a separate thread and pass buffers over a queue to the main thread to do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **AVIOContext** to make a custom read function which will allow you to read data from a buffer instead of video file. The following link might give you some hint
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/489450/Creating-Custom-FFmpeg-IO-Context